# Rails 4 - Finding objects by join table condition

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

I have two models, `User` and `Team`, it's a `many-to-many` with a join table called `Member`. It's set ut like this:

```
#Team:
has_many :members, dependent: :destroy
has_many :users, through: :members 

#User
has_many :members
has_many :teams, through: :members

#Member
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :team
```

I want users to be able to visit each others profile pages (`controller: :users, action: :show`). On the profile page I only want to list the teams that both users are members of (they can be members of different teams as well).

What I've trie is this:

```
#UsersController
def show 
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  @teams = @user.teams.joins(:members).where(:members => { :user_id => current_user.id })
end
```

This doesn't work (no team is displayed in some cases, and the wrong teams is displayed in others, total fail!)

So, what is the correct way to do what I want? Only list the teams the both users are members of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find team_ids you want simply by intersecting:

```
@teams = Team.find(@user.members.pluck(:team_id) & current_user.members.pluck(:team_id))
```

Note: if you had the members collections already loaded you could use `collect(&:team_id)` instead of `pluck(:id)` to save extra calls to database.