# Rails 4 - Thinking-Sphinx, search with condition in join table

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

I have four models, `User`, `Team`, `Idea` and `Member`. `Member` is  join table between `Team` and `User`. I want users to be able to visits each others profile pages (`controller: :users, action: :show`), in the `show` view I want to list `Ideas` that belongs to teams that both users are members of. I've created a related question for listing the correct teams [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25828100/rails-4-finding-objects-by-join-table-condition).

Here is what I have now:

```
def show

  @user = User.find(params[:id])

  # Only list teams that both users are members of
  @teams = @user.teams.find(@user.members.pluck(:team_id) & current_user.members.pluck(:team_id))

  # What should I do to list ideas that are created for teams the both users are members of?
  @ideas = @user.ideas.search(params[:search], conditions: { 'how should the condition look?' } :page => params[:page], :per_page => 10, :order => 'created_at DESC')

end
```

My models is set up like this:

have two models, User and Team, it's a many-to-many with a join table called Member. It's set ut like this:

```
#Team:
has_many :members, dependent: :destroy
has_many :users, through: :members 

#User
has_many :members
has_many :teams, through: :members

#Member
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :team

#Idea
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :team
```

Any ideas on what I should do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want the following attribute in your Idea index (if you haven't already):

```
has team_id
```

And then the following should do the trick (given the existing context of your controller):

```
@ideas = Idea.search params[:search],
  :with     => {:team_id => @teams.collect(&:id)},
  :page     => params[:page],
  :per_page => 10,
  :order    => 'created_at DESC'
```

You do *not* want to direct the idea search through `@user.ideas` - that will limit it to only ideas attached to `@user` *and* their corresponding teams, not `current_user`'s teams.